# Java8: Create HashMap with character count of a String

Tags: java, string, collections, hashmap

Wondering is there more simple way than computing the character count of a given string as below?

```
String word = "AAABBB";
    Map<String, Integer> charCount = new HashMap();
    for(String charr: word.split("")){
        Integer added = charCount.putIfAbsent(charr, 1);
        if(added != null)
            charCount.computeIfPresent(charr,(k,v) -> v+1);
    }

    System.out.println(charCount);
```

Comment: For ANSI characters, you can just have an array of size 256 and compute it.

Comment: @vivek_23 Which [ANSI character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set) would that be? Or did you mean ASCII and 128?

Comment: @vivek_23 that is the windows code page 1252, not ANSI. The Unicode standard matches the iso-latin-1 character set for the first 256 codepoints. Referring to the windows code page 1252 is an unnecessary complication, as that code page does not match in the 128-159 range.

Comment: @Holger Ahh! Thanks for the correction. Deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest way to count occurrence of each character in a string, with full Unicode support (Java 11+)<sup>1</sup>:

```
String word = "AAABBB";
Map<String, Long> charCount = word.codePoints().mapToObj(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(charCount);
```

<sup>1) Java 8 version with full Unicode support is at the end of the answer.</sup>

*Output*

```
{A=3, B=3}
```

---

*UPDATE:* For Java 8+ (doesn't support characters from supplemental planes, e.g. emoji):

```
Map<String, Long> charCount = IntStream.range(0, word.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> word.substring(i, i + 1))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

---

*UPDATE 2:* Also for Java 8+.

I was mistaken, thinking that [`codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) wasn't added until Java 9. It was added in Java 8 to the [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface, so it doesn't show in javadoc for [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#method.summary) in Java 8, and shows as [added in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) for later versions of the javadoc.

However, the [`Character.toString​(int codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) method wasn't added until Java 11, so to use the [`Character.toString​(char c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString-char-) method, we can use [`chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) in Java 8:

```
Map<String, Long> charCount = word.chars().mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Or for full Unicode support, incl. supplemental planes, we can use [`codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) and the [`String(int[] codePoints, int offset, int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-int:A-int-int-) constructor, in Java 8:

```
Map<String, Long> charCount = word.codePoints()
        .mapToObj(cp -> new String(new int[] { cp }, 0, 1))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Am sorry, is there a simple way for Java 8?

Comment: Speaking of “full Unicode support” and Emojis, it’s worth pointing out that even using codepoints is not necessarily providing the intended semantics. E.g. `"ā̧‍"` has 10 chars, 7 codepoints, but only three characters; the first one demonstrates that this is not only an Emoji issue. The only solution, I currently know of, is to process *grapheme clusters*, e.g. with Java 9+: `Pattern.compile("\\X").matcher(example).results() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MatchResult::group, Collectors.counting()))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
     String str = "Hello Manash";
    Map<Character,Long> hm = str.chars().mapToObj(c-> 
    (char)c).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c->c,Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(hm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below approaches:

Approach 1:

```
    String str = "abcaadcbcb";
    
    Map<Character, Integer> charCount = str.chars()
            .boxed()
            .collect(toMap(
                    k -> (char) k.intValue(),
                    v -> 1,         // 1 occurence
                    Integer::sum));
    System.out.println("Char Counts:\n" + charCount);
```

Approach 2:

```
    String str = "abcaadcbcb";
    Map<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        charCount.merge(c,          // key = char
                1,                  // value to merge
                Integer::sum);      // counting
    }
    System.out.println("Char Counts:\n" + charCount);
```

Output:

```
    Char Counts:
    {a=3, b=3, c=3, d=1}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
    List<Character> chars=Arrays.asList('h','e','l','l','o','w','o','r','l','d');
    Map<Character,Long> map=chars.stream().map(c->c).
    collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c->c,Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(map);
```

output:

```
{r=1, d=1, e=1, w=1, h=1, l=3, o=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word.chars().mapToObj(c-> (char)c).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

This will give you character count in order of appearance of the character.

Comment: MIght you format your code snippet as coded, to allow for greater readability? Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "abcaadcbcb";

Map<String, Long> charCount  = 
Arrays.asList(str.split("")).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library that works with Java 8 or above, [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) (EC) can solve this problem using a primitive  `Bag` to count characters. Use a `CharBag` if `char` values are required, or an `IntBag` if codePoints (`int` values) are required. A `Bag` is a simpler data structure for counting things and may be backed by a primitive `HashMap` so as not to box the counts as `Integer` or `Long` objects. A `Bag` doesn't suffer from the missing keys return `null` values problem that a `HashMap` does in Java.

```
@Test
public void characterCountJava8()
{
    String word = "AAABBB";
    CharAdapter chars = Strings.asChars(word);
    CharBag charCounts = chars.toBag();

    Assertions.assertEquals(3, charCounts.occurrencesOf('A'));
    Assertions.assertEquals(3, charCounts.occurrencesOf('B'));
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, charCounts.occurrencesOf('C'));

    System.out.println(charCounts.toStringOfItemToCount());
}
```

Outputs:

```
{A=3, B=3}
```

`CharAdapter` and `CharBag` are primitive collection types available in EC. A `CharBag` is useful if you want to count `char` values. Notice that the `charCounts.occurrencesOf('C')` returns `0` instead of `null` as it would if this was a `HashMap`.

The following example shows using codePoints that are visually appealing using emojis. The code itself will work with Java 8, but I believe the Emoji literal support wasn't added until Java 11.

```
@Test
public void codePointCountJava11()
{
    String emojis = "";
    CodePointAdapter codePoints = Strings.asCodePoints(emojis);
    IntBag emojiCounts = codePoints.toBag();

    int appleInt = "".codePointAt(0);
    int bananaInt = "".codePointAt(0);
    int pearInt = "".codePointAt(0);
    Assertions.assertEquals(3, emojiCounts.occurrencesOf(appleInt));
    Assertions.assertEquals(2, emojiCounts.occurrencesOf(bananaInt));
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, emojiCounts.occurrencesOf(pearInt));

    System.out.println(emojiCounts.toStringOfItemToCount());

    Bag<String> emojiStringCounts = emojiCounts.collect(Character::toString);

    System.out.println(emojiStringCounts.toStringOfItemToCount());
}
```

Outputs:

```
{127820=2, 127822=3}  // IntBag.toStringOfItemToCount()
{=2, =3}          // Bag<String>.toStringOfItemToCount()
```

`CodePointAdapter` and `IntBag` are primitive collection types available in EC. An `IntBag` is useful if you want to count `int` values. Notice that the `emojiCounts.occurrencesOf(pearInt)` returns `0` instead of `null` as it would if this was a `HashMap`.

I converted the `IntBag` to a `Bag<String>` to show the differences when printing `int` vs. `char`. You need to convert `int` codePoints back to `String` if you want to print anything.

The comment Holger left on the accepted answer about grapheme clusters was insightful and helpful. Thank you! The codepoint solution here suffers from the same issue as all of the other codepoint solutions.

Eclipse Collections 11.1 was compiled and released with Java 8. I wouldn't recommend staying on Java 8 any more, but wanted to point out this is still possible.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Java stream solution for this, I hope the code is self-explanatory.

```
String s = "ccacbbaac"
Map<Character, Long> collect = s.chars().mapToObj(y -> (char) y).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> (char) x, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help : Java 8 Stream & Collector:

```
    String word = "AAABBB";
    Map<Character, Integer> charCount = word.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    k -> Character.valueOf((char) k.intValue()),
                    v -> 1,
                    Integer::sum));
    System.out.println(charCount);

Output:
    {A=3, B=3}
```

Comment: `chars()` requires Java 9, and better solution using `codePoints()` instead of `chars()` already posted 13 minutes earlier.

Comment: @Andreas agree with`codePoints()`solution, but`chars()`introduce in java 8 [String.chars()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--)

Comment: That would be `CharSequence.chars()`, not `String.chars()`, but I accept your correction. [Javadoc for Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) show method as added to `String` in Java 9, which is what lead me astray.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, below is another simple way.

```
Map<String, Integer> charCount = new HashMap();
    for(String charr: s.split("")){
        charCount.put(charr,charCount.getOrDefault(charr,0)+1);
}
```

Comment: `charCount.put(charr,charCount.getOrDefault(charr,0)+1);` can be simplified to `charCount.merge(charr, 1, Integer::sum);` By the way, you should use `new HashMap<>()`…

Answer (score 0):

Simple Java 8 solution I can think is:

```
Map<String, Long> map= Arrays.stream(word.trim().toLowerCase().split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
String str = "edcba"

Map<String, Long> couterMap1 = str.codePoints()
                                  .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: I get compilation error as "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <U> mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U>)"